# CRM Plugin executing several times

Tags: email, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, infinite-loop, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to create a plugin on CRM 2011 online to notify users by mail when an opportunity is updated.

In the email, I need to have the value of some fields before and after the update.

So, I'm using Post operation on update message for the opportunity entity with the pre and post image.

It's working well if I update any fields except for the owner of the opportunity. I changed it, I get two emails generated. One with the owner who owns the record before the update and one with the owner who owns the record after the update. So I supposed that the plugins is called twice.

I think that I have an infinite loop in my plugin and I take a look at the depth property but it's not working for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owner is updated using other then Update message - Assign message is used. So I assume that behaviour of your plugin is correct.

Comment: From what I understand, changing the owner use update and assign message but I only use the update message in my plugin and it's excecuting twice. I think to split the plugin in two parts : 1 for the fields (update) and one for the owner (assign). What do you think about this ?

Comment: I believe that would be correct to split plugin and logic on mentioned parts.

Comment: I will do it in this way. Thanks for your help :)